# Writing Assembly Code for a Tattoo

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am requesting help with writing 32-bit assembly code for a simple "program tattoo.”

I would like to get a tattoo.  After thinking it over, I have decided that I would like a tattoo that uses assembly code and deals with my daughter, Alisha.  My idea is come up with an "illogical computation," one that defies the laws of assembly language.  I want to pay homage to how illogical having a child seems to someone like me... someone who is used to 1s and 0s.

I'm thinking of using x86-based 32-bit registers like EAX, EBX, and ECX and of course some pushes and pops.

The tattoo would NOT have the comments (nothing in parentheses), but would include the start: notation.

```
start:
    mov eax, 53656C66h   (ASCII for "Self")
    mov ebx, 57696665h   (ASCII for "Wife")
    add ebx, eax

    push ebx
    push 3F81DBh         (Decimal 4162011 = daughter's birth date)

    pop ecx              (The first pop would give my daughter's birth date)
    pop ecx              (the second pop would NOT give the answer of eax added to ebx,
                          but would rather give my daughter’s nickname)
    ??? ecx
```

My idea is to replace ??? with the instruction to read and then show that the value in ecx is now 416c69h (ASCII for "Ali," my daughter's nickname).  I think this idea would be awesome, and I will post pictures of the tattoo if I get it (of course).

My idea is that the last pop would defy computer logic.  In essence, having a child defies the "logic" that we know, so this was my attempt to parallel the beauty of birth.

Any other ideas?

Comment: bx is a 16 bit register. The value 5769666579h is 31bit long... Maybe you should consider another idea...

Comment: Good point Macmade. I just switched to using the extended registers. Actually, ACSII uses 7 bits per char, right?  Meaning that I would need to use 64-bits to hold "Alisha" in ASCII.  I could use "Ali," since that is her nickname.

Comment: Won't you want to get a 64 bit tattoo?

Comment: wifey doesn't fit into 32 bit, BTW

Comment: The instruction to "read" a value is `mov`. You need to specify where you want to put the value you have read. If you want to compare the value, you need `cmp`.

Comment: drhirsch> Thank you.  I will switch to using "Wife," which is only four ASCII letters, thus only 28-bits :).

Comment: Nice tattoo idea. Just be sure to have a good tattoo kit for that :)

Answer (score 6):

What's a bit weird is that the program does nothing, really.
Why not instead write code that results in your daughter's name as a result of combining things such as your name, your wife's, and some encoding of her birth date? Perhaps through a series of `XOR` instructions with some meaningful values?

Comment: My idea was that the last pop would defy the normal computer logic.  Rather than returning the answer of 5769666579h + 4d65h, it would return my daughter's name.  However, I really like your idea.  Now, I just need to find out how to go about some XORs to derive "Ali" in hex from "Me" and my wife's nick/name.  I also need to find out how to fit these stuff better into registers... I would prefer to stick with 32-bit at this point.

Comment: Do I want to begin with movs or should I load the registers rather than move in a value?  I'm not sure what the best way to fill an empty register is in assembly.  In other words, I would like to begin the program by bringing in "Me" (ASCII as hex) and "Wife" (ASCII as hex).  Once I bring in the values, I'd like to start XORing them with things like birthdate/special dates/etc. in order to get my daughter's name from the XORs.  This will be tricky!

Comment: You can do `mov eax, 'Wife'`, this will be understood by the assembler.

Comment: drhirsch> I was going for the obfuscation of using hex values, since it's not as obvious. I like the idea that most people won't have any clue what they're looking at :)